# How do lifetime bounds on structs work in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

There was some discussion of this in IRC yesterday, which left me feeling vaguely dissatisfied.

The question was:

> How do you define a lifetime on a struct to restrict its contents to
>   only things that live as long as 'itself'.

i.e. a `'self` sort of thing.

My initial reaction was: you can't.

If you create a struct `Foo<'a>`, the lifetime associated with it is inferred from the references it contains; unless the struct contains a reference to *itself* (impossible), you can't have this sort of `'self` lifetime.

There was a bunch of chatter about it, and I ended up writing [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f2c1749f96d06b1ed376a92296a43287) as a result:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
  a:&'a Bar,
  b:&'a Bar
}

fn factory<'a>(v1:&'a Bar, v2: &'a Bar) -> Foo<'a> {
  return Foo {
    a: v1,
    b: v2
  };
}

fn main() { // <---- Let's call this block lifetime 'one
  let a = Bar; 
  let c = &a; // <-- C has lifetime 'one
  { // <------------ Let's call this block lifetime 'two
    let b = Bar;

    let mut foo1 = factory(c, c);  
    foo1.b = &b;

    let mut foo2 = factory(&b, &b);  
    foo2.a = &a;

    println!("{:?}", foo1);
    println!("{:?}", foo2);
  }
}
```

However, I'm now more confused rather than less.

So, in a strict sense in the above:

- `c` has `'one`
- `&b` has `'two`
- `'static` > `'one` > `'two` (that is, `'two` is bounded by `'one`).
- `foo1` has `'one`
- `foo2` has `'two`

Now, my confusion:

`Foo<'a>` indicates that `'a` is the *minimum lifetime bound* that can be contained by the instance of `Foo`.

- Since `'one` > `'two`, `foo2` should be able contain a `&'one a`; this works.
- Since `'two` > `'one`, `foo1` should *not* be able to contain `&'two b`; however, this works.

Why?

It would appear my confusion results from one of two misconceptions; either:

1. The instance of `foo1` is in fact `Foo<'two>`, not `Foo<'one>`.

   I don't understand why this would be the case, since it is manufactured in `factory<'a>` where `<'a>` is the lifetime of `c`; which is `'one`, not `'two`. There's absolutely no way `c` can be `&'two` in the example above. The lifetime `'two` is not available in the function factory where `Foo` is created.

2) Struct lifetimes don't work how I understand them to work; i.e. a lifetime of `'a` on a `Foo` instance can somehow change between after the instance is created (e.g. on a move?)

...but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lifetime parameters on references are *covariant*: they can be substituted with a *shorter* lifetime when necessary.

Basically, you've got it the wrong way around. When you have a `&'one Bar`, you cannot assign a reference to a value with a *shorter* lifetime (such as `'two` here), otherwise the reference would be dangling when execution leaves the `'two` scope. However, when you have a `&'two Bar`, you can assign a reference to a value with a longer lifetime (such as `'one` and `'static`), because the reference will go out of scope before the referent does.

Why does your program compile?  The compiler doesn't only use information from the calls to `factory` to select the appropriate lifetime; [it also uses information from the assignments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/types/inference.html). `&a` has type `&'one Bar` and `&b` has type `&'two Bar`. Because `'two` starts after `'one` and ends before `'one`, the compiler can **coerce** a `&'one Bar` to a `&'two Bar`. In object-oriented terms, a `&'one Bar` *is a* `&'two Bar` (`&'one Bar` is a subtype of `&'two Bar`). Just like how in Java, you can pass a `String` as an argument to a function that expects an `Object`. The subtyping relation for classes in Java is that child classes are subtypes of their parents, but the subtyping relation for lifetimes is that longer lifetimes are subtypes of shorter ones.

This means that we've found a common type for `&a` and `&b`: `&'two Bar`. Therefore, the compiler infers `'two` for `'a` in the calls to `factory`.

Note that the type of `foo2` doesn't change at the assignment; the type of a value is always static.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect that you're right, I got them the wrong way around, but no... I still don't understand why the instances both are Foo<'two>.

Comment: Edited to elaborate on the subtyping relation between lifetimes.